# Find a users location and display specific HTML code

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Show Content Only to Users in a Geo Location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200652/show-content-only-to-users-in-a-geo-location)

Does anyone know of a php or jquery script that I can use to find a users location and display certain HTML code just for that location/country?

Comment: geoip package ? http://pecl.php.net/package/geoip

Comment: can someone tell me why this was voted down?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use getTimezoneOffset() in javascript to get the local system's timezone and based on that populate your html containers with specific content. Just my two cents.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettimezoneoffset.asp